# L298N Gradual Voltage Drop

Tags: l298n

I have connected my motors to L298N and it in turn to arduino. My battery is ~18 V and i used a boost converter to get 12.99V. When I run my program on Arduino Mega, I check the output voltage from the motor drive and observe that it begins from somewhere 11.99V and goes gradually down like 11.70,11.63,11.55..... till 4.03 V then it does not go down. I am attaching my circuit as a photo here. I hope sonebody could help me to find my mistake
[image: my circuit on paper]

Comment: Are you measuring voltage across motor's two terminal?

Comment: @Fahad yes, I measured voltage on the output of the motor driver. So without connecting the motor. But even when I connect the motor to the drive the motor begins to turn and because of the gradual voltage drop it stops then.

Comment: How about voltages on battery and buck converter? What happens if you wire logic levels to run the motor directly (without arduino)? Anyway you should count with the voltage drop on transistors used inside of L298 and they are two of them for single motor...

Comment: @KIIV the battery voltage is near 17.65V and on the output of the buck converter i get 12.99 V. Motors work directly connected to battery very well. And for the L298N there should be max 2 V drop. But it drops gradually until 4 V

Comment: So, voltage drops even without connecting the motors?

Comment: @Fahad yes, exatly

Comment: The connection diagram is correct. It's either a faulty L298 or buck converter. When the voltage drops to 4v check the voltage across buck converter. If it's still 12v, you know what to change.

Comment: @Fahad okay, that is a good way of determining the problematic part in the circuit.Thank you !